# Mean number of tosses to obtain a given sequence of heads and tails

Tags: probability-theory

> What is the expectation of the number of tosses needed to obtain a given sequence of heads and tails if the  coin is fair and the coin is tossed until we get  this sequence?

For exemple what is the expectation of the number of tosses needed to obtain `htht`?

Comment: Hint: Write a linear system solved by $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$, where $e_i$ denotes the mean hitting time of the prefix of length $i$ of the word of interest. For example, for the word $htht$ and $i=3$, note that once $ht$ is hit, either the next letter is $h$ and then one hits $hth$ the next step, or the next letter is $t$, and one now has to hit $hth$ starting from nothing, thus, $$e_3=e_2+1+\tfrac12\cdot e_3.$$ Finally, solve the system for $e_4$.